# Добавить тект к google maps кластерам

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api

Делаю подключение к google maps все работает, но не могу понять как текс при наведении на кластер добавить. Потому как из бд данные подгружаются и у каждого кластера свои данные, как это реализовать?

```js
      function initMap() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 9,
          center: {lat: 57.606750501032174, lng: 39.3559455871582},
          navigationControl: true,
    styles: [
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#212121"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#212121"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.country",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#bdbdbd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#181818"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#1b1b1b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#2c2c2c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#8a8a8a"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#373737"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#3c3c3c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#4e4e4e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#3d3d3d"
      }
    ]
  }
]
});

        // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
        var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        // Add some markers to the map.
        // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
        // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
        // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
        var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            label: labels[i % labels.length]
          });
        });

        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
      }
      var locations = [
                {lat: 57.606750501032174, lng: 39.3559455871582},
                {lat: 57.606750501032174, lng: 39.3559455871582},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.62146171344325, lng: 39.8173713684082},
                {lat: 57.12146171344325, lng: 39.9173713684082},
             
        {lat: 0, lng: 0}
      ]
```

```css
#map {
    position: absolute!important;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.map_place {
    background-color: unset !important;
}
.text_scroll_arrows {
    top: 0;
}
.map_objects_list{
    height: 280px;
}
.big_close{
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD3GRKDAxRHJbTG8ErTVFnzjWQtLEdVcJo&callback=initMap">
</script>   
<div id="map"></div>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а типа `attr("title","text text ")` не получится ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский можете в коде показать как, пожалуйста

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3955258/6339052

Comment: @МаксимЛенский  это если один кластер а если их много

Comment: так и делать для каждого наверно ... у нас все сервисы Google выключены, не имеем доступа - заблокированно но по идее просто добавить на любую метку - обычный attr можно и это будет проще

Comment: @МаксимЛенский ну не могу понять 4 часа уже можете в коде написать

Comment: не могу - не работает у  меня Google - понимаете ?